# Initializing const member variables of a singleton

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

Here is what I try to do (as the title of the question might not describe the entire problem well).

In the program I would like to write, I need to dynamically create instances of an object which I store in a vector list.

```
class A {...};
int main()
{
    std::vector<A *> as;
    as.push_back(new A);
    as.push_back(new A);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Once the vector has have been filled up with "As" I would like to "pass it on" to a singleton object.

```
class Singleton
{
private:
    Singleton() {}
    // set this with the content of ::as created in main?
    const std::vector<A*> as;
public:
    Singleton& instance()
    {
        // how can I set 'as' before the instance is returned/even created?
        static Singleton instance; return instance;
    }
};
...
int main(...)
{
    std::vector<A *> as;
    as.push_back(new A);
    as.push_back(new A);
    ...
    // I'd like Singleton::as to be set with the content of 'as'
    // before I use the singleton for the first time?
    Singleton::instance.doSomethingWithAs();
    return 0;
}
```

Ideally I'd like to find a way of passing the vector list declared in main() to to the singleton and being sure that the "as" in the Singleton aren't modifiable anymore (hence the const).

The reason for this is because I'd like then the Singleton to keep reusing objects from the vector list (Singleton::as), but I want to be sure that at no point in the program, this list gets modified once the Singleton is being used.

I did my best to describe what I would like to do. Maybe there is a pattern for doing this. I have no idea if this design make sense or more importantly I can't see how to implement something like this (I can't seem to find a way of initializing a const member variables of Singleton before the singleton is being used - it seems to defy the concept of the Singleton itself, since `static Singleton instance` will be created as soon as the program is run).

It seems like it might be possible if I somehow declare std::vector not in main() but as a global variable, but I'd like to avoid using global variable if possible.

Any suggestion, help, ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to initialize a `const` member of an object, you *must* do it in the initializer list of the constructor. That means you are forced to make it part of the `instance` function. You can layer this so that `instance` doesn't take a parameter, but calls `create_instance` which does.

```
Singleton(const vector<A*> * init) : as(*init)
{
}

Singleton& create_instance(const vector<A*> * init)
{
    static Singleton instance(init);
    return instance;
}

Singleton& instance()
{
    return create_instance(null_ptr);
}
```

For completeness you should put some error checking that throws an exception if `create_instance` is called more than once with a non-null parameter.

Comment: Thanks, very good idea. It is similar to the other answers in a way but I like it most as suggested in my comment below because there's only one possible way of calling `instance()`. It would be great to know from experts if my design makes any sense?

Answer (score 1):

You may initialize the const member in constructor with an helper method:

```
std::vector<A*> make_as()
{
    std::vector<A*> as;
    as.push_back(new A);
    as.push_back(new A);
    //..
    return as;
}

Singleton::Singleton() : as(make_as()){}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good answer but not as complete as the others. But thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `as` as a pointer in `instance` method parameter, which has default value `nullptr`, example below:

note that I have changes `instance` method to be `static`. Whether this is a good design, I don't know, I have never used code like that.

```
class A {};

class Singleton
{
private:
    Singleton(std::vector<A *>* p) : as(*p)  {}
    // set this with the content of ::as created in main?
    const std::vector<A*> as;
public:
    static Singleton& instance(std::vector<A *>* p=nullptr)
    {
        // how can I set 'as' before the instance is returned/even created?
        static Singleton instance(p); return instance;
    }

    void useMe() {
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A *> as;
    as.push_back(new A);
    as.push_back(new A);
Singleton::instance(&as);

Singleton::instance().useMe();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I tried this approach and it sort of worked, but I didn't like the design of it so much because you can use instance() in 2 different ways. Plus I am not sure what we will happens if `instance(&as)` is called more than one time?